# Why can't I float my navbar elements to the right when I use bootstrap's css file?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a navbar to start my website out with but I'm having an issue with the css files that I'm working with. Primarily bootstrap's css file. I linked both my custom css file and bootstrap's to my html file, but I can't get my navbar to float to the right as long as bootstrap's css file is linked. I tried switching the order of the linked css files but to no avail. What does work is if I delete the bootstrap linked file but I want to practice working with bootstraps grid system in this project. As always help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    color:beige;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

/*Add the background-color to <ul> instead of each <a> element if you want a full-width background color*/
li a {
    display: block;
    color: beige;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainnature.css">
    
    
    

    <title>Nature Conservatory</title>
    
  </head>
  

  <body>
  <header> 
  <nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Volunteer</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">Search</a></li>
</ul>
 </nav>
  </header>
  
   
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add `!important` to every attribute in your costum css files to make sure that your style is prior than bootstrap style

Comment: you don't need important!. TL;DR https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 uses display Flex for alignment so floats don't do what they would in a `display: block` situation. iacobalin is correct that you need to use justify content, but [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) already provides a `justify-content-end` class that you can add to your `nav.navbar` and a `.nav` class that you can add to your `ul` without needing to add more lines to your custom css.

```css
ul {
    /* list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding:0;
     overflow:hidden;*/
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    color:beige;
}

/* li {
     display: inline;
     float: right;
 }*/

/*Add the background-color to <ul> instead of each <a> element if you want a full-width background color*/
li a {
    display: block;
    color: beige;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainnature.css">
    
    
    

    <title>Nature Conservatory</title>
    
  </head>
  

  <body>
  <header> 
  <nav class="navbar justify-content-end">
  <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="default.asp">Volunteer</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">Search</a></li>
</ul>
 </nav>
  </header>
  
   
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your .navbar class change `justify-content` value to `flex-end;` Or if you don't want to change bootstrap defaults just add an id or extra class name to you navbar:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    color:beige;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

/*Add the background-color to <ul> instead of each <a> element if you want a full-width background color*/
li a {
    display: block;
    color: beige;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar.float-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainnature.css">
    
    
    

    <title>Nature Conservatory</title>
    
  </head>
  

  <body>
  <header> 
  <nav class="navbar float-right">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Volunteer</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">Search</a></li>
</ul>
 </nav>
  </header>
  
   
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to float elements to the right since the class `.nabvar` is set `display: flex` by default on bootstrap. You just need to add the following to your `.nabvar` class:

```
 .nabvar
 {
    justify-content: flex-end;
 }
```

Additionally, if you `float: right` your `li` elements you'll get them arranged backwords, my advice is to remove that line of code